# jquery call function for the particular class which is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

html:

```
 <div class="a">

   <div class="g"></div>
   <a class="e">Link</a>

  <div class="g"></div>
   <a class="e">Link</a>

</div>
```

I want to hide the div with class "g" whenever I click on the link.Only that particular link.Suppose if i clicked on the first link then the first div with class "g" should hide only.Now wat i've done is here.

Jquery:

```
    $('.e').click(function(){
               c();
       });

    function c(){
          $(.g).hide();
      }
```

but this is hiding all the elements of class "g".

Both the div with class "g" and link are generated by the users dynamically and i dont know how many the users can generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currenctly you are calling `$('.g').hide()` which is selecting all the element with g as the class and hiding them all.

Instead use `prev()` to select element which you want to hide

```
       $('.e').click(function(){
              jQuery(this).prev().hide();
       });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/NQYN4/1/)

Updated as per comment:

You can use this code:

```
$('.e').click(function(){
              c(this);
       });

function c(element){
          $(element).prev().hide();
      }
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/NQYN4/2/)

Comment: if i've to do this in the function c() than how will i do it?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(".e").click(function(){
   $(this).closest("div.g").hide();
})
```

or:

```
var elem = "";
$(".e").click(function(){
       elem = $(this).closest("div.g");
       c(elem);
    })

function c(elem) {
$(elem).hide();
}
```

Comment: i want to do the same work in the function how will i do the same thing in the function c();

Answer (score 1):

with the function c():

```
$('.e').click(function(){
    c(this);
});

function c(element){
    $(element).prev().hide();
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NQYN4/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with jQuery each() method, with your HTML staying the same and JavaScript as follows;

```
$(".e").each(function () {

  // $(this) refers to that particular link not all the links.
  $(this).click(function (e) {

    /**
     * as a precaution for preventing anchor
     * to redirect/scroll to location defined in "href" attribute
     */
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).prev(".g").hide();
  });
});
```